# Repurpose NFC credit card for personal use

Tags: nfc

I have my old NFC credit card which is inactive. I am trying to repurpose my old NFC credit card as "WiFi NFC tag. I have tried formatting with my Android phone NFC app. I have tried with multiple application and it fails to write on the card.

Is there a way I can do it? Is there any windows, android or linux app that can help me in doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Er No.

Usually these cards by design are read only.

Comment: But wouldn't it be possible to develop an app for automation for instance that would trigger actions when the credit card is detected?

Comment: @bkqc Yes you could develop an app to do something when it was an old NFC card is detected, but that was not the question and is a lot more complicated spending a very small amount of money to buy a writeable NFC Tag